# I am trying to map through array loaded from TMDB API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I uploaded my Data using FETCH from the TMDB API , When i try to map through it , it gives me an error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NowMovies.map')

this is my code :

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      NowMovies:[],
      isLoaded:false
    }
  }

    componentDidMount(){
     fetch('API')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(({MoviesLists}) => {this.setState({
      isLoaded:true,
      NowMovies:MoviesLists
    })
    })
    }
  render(){
    var {isLoaded,NowMovies} = this.state
    if (!isLoaded){
      return <div> .... Loading</div>
    }
    else{
    return(
      <div>

      <ul>  
      {NowMovies.map(Movie=>(<li key={NowMovies.id}> name:{NowMovies.original_title}</li>
      ))}
      </ul>
      </div>
```

[this is what the API loades](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YVLr.png)

can anyone help me with loading this data to my array and map through it??

Comment: Please fix the formatting: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: There's no `MoviesLists` property in the response.

Comment: @Andreas I will sorry for the messed up format , I changed the data => data.json to MoviesLists.json the error is now over but the array were not loaded with the data what do you suggest , Thank you

Comment: @Hazem Which is your API?

Comment: @ForamTrada  TMDB

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `NowMovies` within the map function, you should use the `Movie` object you've passed instead.

```js
{NowMovies.map(Movie =>(
  <li key={Movie.id}> 
    name:{Movie.original_title}
  </li>
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I fixed this but there is a problem in loading the data in the NowMovies array as it still shows me ... loading 

`  componentDidMount(){
     fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=c71a7b8c45890b633f3719b41ed7996b&language=en-US&page=1')
    .then(data => MoviesList.json())
    .then(({MoviesList}) => {this.setState({
      isLoaded:true,
      NowMovies:MoviesList
    })
    })
    }`

Comment: Try this. `.then(data => data.json()).then(({results}) => { this.setState({ isLoaded: true, NowMovies: results })})}`

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign directly the value, for that you can use .concat() or .push().
And correct with .map().

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      NowMovies:[],
      isLoaded:false
    }
  }

    componentDidMount(){
     fetch(API)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then(({MoviesLists}) => {
  let movieList = this.state.NowMovies.concat(MoviesLists);
this.setState({
      isLoaded:true,
      NowMovies : movieList
    })
    })
    }
  render(){
    var {isLoaded,NowMovies} = this.state
    if (!isLoaded){
      return <div> .... Loading</div>
    }
    else{
    return(
      <div>
      <ul>  
      {NowMovies.map(Movie=>(<li key={Movie.id}> name:{Movie.original_title}</li>
      ))}
      </ul>
      </div>
```